# Node js functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node.js and can't figure out how to create and use functions. For example in my code:-

```
var abc={
    printFirstName:function(){
        console.log("My name is abc");
        console.log(this===abc);   //Prints true
    }
};
abc.printFirstName();

//The default calling context is global
function worthless(){
    console.log("I'm worthless");
    console.log(this===global);   //Prints true
}
worthless();
```

I can't understand the difference between the function I've written inside the variable abc and the function I've written outside it. I tried writing the printFirstName function as

```
function printFistName(){ //First Case
     console.log("My name is abc");
     console.log(this===abc);
}
```

But it gives me an error. Similarly, I tried writing the global function as

```
worthless:function(){ //Second Case
    console.log("I'm worthless");
    console.log(this===global);
}
```

and it gives me an error. I can't understand how this works. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:-**

Here's the error I get in the first case:

```
function printFirstName(){
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:240:19)
```

And here's the error I get in the second case:

```
worthless:function(){
                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:240:19)
```

Comment: Well in the second case you don't have a variable `abc`, so what do you expect `console.log(this===abc);` to do? In the third case you are trying to create a function without a name which doesn't work with [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: "gives me an error" - the error message tells exactly what is wrong with your code. If you copy it here (please edit your post), we can help you understand it.

Comment: It looks like you haven't shown the complete code in the second case since it doesn't produce the syntax you claim it does. It could though if there is other code before it.

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet above, the function `printFirstName` in the object `abc` is an object method, which implies that function calls to this function will use the object's context, like so:

```
var obj = {
   foo: 'bar',
   func: function () {
       console.log(this.foo); // this prints 'bar'
   }
};
```

On the other hand, the function `printFirstName` is in the outer scope. If your code is running in non-[strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), all references to `this` in the function correspond to `global`, which is the root object for all global entities like `console`, and so on. If strict mode is enabled, all references to `this` evaluate to `undefined`.

You'd also want to take a look at https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md, which explains this in great detail.

As for the attempt at writing `printFirstName` outside the object `abc`, I see that there's a typo: `printFistName`, which could be leading to an error of the form: `ReferenceError: printFistName is not defined`.

Moving on to the last snippet:

```
worthless: function () {
    console.log("I'm worthless");
    console.log(this === global);
}
```

The above syntax is meant to declare the function as a property called `worthless`, and will result in an `Unexpected token SyntaxError` error when run as a part of a script.